# python magic square and area of a triangle

Tags: python

```
__author__ = 'student'

def is_magic_square(s):
    '''
    Return whether a two dimensional integer array s is magic, that is:
    1) The dimensions of s is nxn
    2) Every integer in [1,2,...,n*n] appears in s, exactly once.
    3) The sum of all rows in s is the same as the sum of all
    columns in s, is the same as the sum of the diagonal
    elements in s.

    :param s: A two dimensional integer array represented as a nested list.
    :return: True if square is magic, False otherwise

example outputs:
>>> is_magic_square([[1]])
True
>>> is_magic_square([[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]])
True


>>> is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
False
>>> is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]])
False

    nrows = len(s)
    ncols = 0
    if nrows != 0:
        ncols = len(s[0])
    if nrows != ncols:
        return False
    m = []
    for column in range(len(s[0])):
        t = 0
        for row in s:
            t += row[column]
        m.append(t)

    m[0] = sum(s[0])
    for row in s:
        sums = 0
        for elem in row:
            sums+=elem
        if sums != m[0]:
            return False
    sum([ s[i][i] for i in range(len(s))]) and  sum([ s[len(s)-i-1][i] for i in range(len(s))])


return True
```

i require a function to tell if when given a matrix: a set of lists. to check and see if they make a magic square. that is if they follow and adhere to the 3 conditions stated above. i have my function working for 3x3 matrix but when i use a 1x1 matrix the output for the check to see if it is a nxn matrix doesn't work 
    ncols = len(s[0])
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

also if someone could tell me why my class triangle doesn't want to return the area in the area portion it says int object not callable:

```
Class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, side1, side2, side3):

        pass
        self.side1 = side1
        self.side2 = side2
        self.side3 = side3

    def get_perimeter(self):
        pass
        return self.side1+self.side2+self.side3

    def get_area(self):
        pass
        p = self.get_perimeter() / 2
        area = math.sqrt((p*(p - self.side1)(p-self.side2)(p-self.side3)))
        return area

    def __str__(self):

    pass 
        s = "A Triangle with side 1 {0} and side 2 {1} and side 3 {2}".format(self.side1, self.side2, self.side3)
        s = s + "area {0} and perimeter {1}".format(self.get_area(), self.get_perimeter())
        return s
```

Comment: Your `get_area()` is missing some `*`s for multiplication.

Comment: Since this is a Q&A site about specific questions, keep it to one question per post.

Comment: Do you mind using numpy for your square, or do you want a pure pythonic implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always advise you to break the problem down into modules. Please check my code below.

```
__author__ = 'student'

def counting_element_frequent(s):
    frequent_list = {}
    for i in s:
        for element in set(i):
            frequent_list[element] = frequent_list.get(element, 0)\
    return frequent_list.values()

def verifyuniqulity(s):
    len_element = sum(counting_element_frequent()) 
    return len_element == len(s)**2

def verifying_dimension_equality(s):
    rows_num = len(s)
    for index, item in enumerate(s):
        if not len(s[index]) == rows_num:
            return False
    return True

def row_sum(s):
    row_addition = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        row_addition.append(sum(s[i]))
    return sum(row_addition)

def column_sum(s):
    column_addition = []
    for j in range(len(s)):
        for k in range(len(s)):
            column_addition.append(s[k][j]) 
    return sum(column_addition)

def diagonal_sum(s):
    diagonal_addition = []
    for v in range(len(s)):
        diagonal_addition.append(s[v][v])
    return sum(diagonal_addition)

def is_magic_square(s):
    ''' 
    Return whether a two dimensional integer array s is magic, that is:
    1) The dimensions of s is nxn
    2) Every integer in [1,2,...,n*n] appears in s, exactly once.
    3) The sum of all rows in s is the same as the sum of all
    columns in s, is the same as the sum of the diagonal
    elements in s.

    :param s: A two dimensional integer array represented as a nested list.
    :return: True if square is magic, False otherwise

    example outputs:
    >>> is_magic_square([[1]])
    True
    >>> is_magic_square([[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]])
    True


    >>> is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
    False
    >>> is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]])
    False
    '''
    if not verifying_dimension_equality(s):
        return False
    elif verifyuniqulity(s):
        row_addition = row_sum(s)
        column_addition = column_sum(s)
        diagonal_addition = diagonal_sum(s)        
        return row_addition == column_addition == diagonal_addition*len(s)
    return False

print is_magic_square([[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]])
print is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print is_magic_square([[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]])
```

Comment: Your algorithm has two more major flaws. In `verifyuniqulity()` you check whether each row appears once in the square, but this doesn't tell you whether a specific number is repeated anywhere else in the square. And because you never actually check whether each column has the same number of elements, the illegal `[[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9, 0], [6, 7, 2]]` passes your test. For additional robustness the code should also check that not only is the iterable a square list of lists, but that all elements are integers. However, that would admittedly complicate the code.